# jquery if parent exist else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know if parent exist then I need to do this else this. Here is the code:

```
if ($('#block-slides p a img.alignleft').parent().length) {
        $(this).parent().parent().css({'max-width' : '100%', 'padding' :   '0'}).addClass('clearfix');
    } else {
        $('#block-slides p img.alignleft').parent().css({'max-width' : '100%', 'padding' : '0'}).addClass('clearfix');
    }
```

But nothing happen. Any help please?

Comment: Post your markup here please.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The link? http://layot.prestatrend.com/

Comment: Reproduce the issue on jsfiddle please

Comment: `... a img.alignleft').parent().length` is always `1` and `true`.

Comment: It's too difficult for me to reproduse it at jsfiddle. I need to know if img.alignleft has parent <a> tag. If has then I need to add to <a> tag parent <p> some css. If no <a> tag add some css to img.alignleft parent, <p> in this case.

Comment: `this` probably doesn't mean what you think it means in that context

Comment: @undefined could be `0` if the selector doesn't return anything in the first place :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...if you're just looking for the `<p>`-element, try:

```
$('#block-slides img.alignleft').closest('p').css({.....});
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/